# Stub client generation Apache CXF

Tags: web-services, cxf, axis, webservice-client

I am seeing one behavior while accessing one wsdl. I used Apache Axis 1.3 as well as JAX-WS wsimport tool to generate client stubs, it is successfully generating stubs.
But when I am using apache-cxf-2.7.18 and using wsdl2java command, it's not generating stubs, giving me error.

WSDL is on https. I added proxy in wsdl2java bat file as well. wsdl contains a  which is also on https.

Error I am getting like:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCcMI.png)

It seems to that it's not able to include underlying wsdl. 
Can anybody give me any pointer what I am doing wrong?

I believe, when I am doing any service publishing, it can not be client implementation specific like it is supported by Axis but not CXF. or I can do that? Is there any restriction that could be applied?

Comment: Probably is a misconfiguration of the proxy in wsdl2java. Seems the executable does not allow to specify the proxy. Did you test with the ant task configuring the proxy environment variables?

Comment: I tried with maven. In settings.xml, I set proxy details. 

wsdl2java failed: org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLRuntimeException: Fail to create wsdl definition file:/C:/test-client/src/main/resources/Sample.wsdl: WSDLException (at /wsdl:definitions/wsdl:import): faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: Problem parsing 'WSDL link - sorry I can't mention'.: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect -> [Help 1]

Comment: In maven, settings.xml I did this
<proxy>
      <id>optional</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <username>XXXXXX</username>
      <password>XXXXXX</password>
      <host>proxy-server.XXXX.com</host>
      <port>8080</port>
      <nonProxyHosts>local.net|some.host.com</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>

Comment: This url is weird `file:/C:/test-client/src/main/resources/Sample.wsdl`. You have said you have a connection problem with SSL, but this url points to a local file instead a `https://` resource

Comment: Try also to change in settings `<protocol>https</protocol>`. I have read in some posts that it works in some cases.

Comment: I downloaded wsdl from https end point URL and placed it under maven project. Then referring that from pom.xml as
                       <wsdlOption>                           <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/Sample.wsdl</wsdl>
                       </wsdlOption>
under <plugin>. 
And from the downloaded wsdl another import exists which is like
<wsdl:import location="https://exampleURL?wsdl=example.wsdl" namespace="http://www.example.com/services/mediation/v2">
    </wsdl:import>
I changed <protocol>https</protocol> but no luck

Comment: Seems maven is not is not able to download imports using your proxy configuration. Since you have downloaded the wsdl, you can also download all referenced url resources to local files and change `<wsdl:import location=` to use each local file. Use a relative path `./yourfile` or a URL format `file://path/to/the/file`

Comment: Yes. That worked for me. Thank you very much.

Comment: I have posted a summary of the comment as an answer. Please consider to mark it as accepted for future use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Solution in comments)

The error log shows a connection error when downloading the WSDL, probably due to a misconfiguration of the proxy in `wsdl2java` when using a SSL connection through maven

Maven is not is not able to download imports using the proxy configuration, since you have  downloaded the wsdl, you can also download all referenced url resources to local files and change `<wsdl:import location=` to use each local file. Use a relative path `./yourfile` or a URL format `file://path/to/the/file`

Comment: But it's strange to me why cxf is not able to get connection over ssl where as axis wsdl2java and jax-ws wsimport tool is able to